# Facing an issue to use SetSourceData method to chart in powerpoint through python

Tags: python, powerpoint

We have written a small peace of code to update the chart data to the existing chart in powerpoint presentation. To update the chart data we are calling the method  '.SetSourceData(Source=)'.
But, it is getting failed by saying:

`'pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147467259), None)'`

Need to resolve the issue as soon as possible.

Input file Link : https://www.sendspace.com/file/a1m5zx

```py
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import traceback


input_file = "C:/input.pptx"
output = "C:/output.pptx"

try:
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    slide_dict = {1: {'Chart 1': 'CHARTTAG_1062'}}
    application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
    excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    presentation = application.Presentations.Open(input_file, ReadOnly=0, Untitled=0, WithWindow=1)

    e_workbook = None
    for idx, Slide in enumerate(presentation.Slides):
        if idx == 0:
            continue
        else:
            print("slide_dict", slide_dict)
            for Shape in Slide.Shapes:
                for each in slide_dict[idx]:
                    if each == Shape.Name:
                        try:
                            chart = Shape.Chart
                            chartdata = chart.ChartData
                            chartdata.Activate()
                            e_workbook = chartdata.Workbook

                            chart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Visible = True
                            e_workbook.Worksheets[0].Select()
                            e_worksheet = e_workbook.ActiveSheet
                            xlUp = -4162
                            lastrow = e_worksheet.Cells(e_worksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            try:
                                e_worksheet.Range("A1:Z" + str(lastrow)).Delete()
                            except Exception as e:
                                print("Error : " + str(e))
                                traceback.print_exc()
                            count = 2
                            chart_header = [' # Data 1 ', ' # Data2 ']
                            chart_data = [
                                          [
                                            "Category 1",
                                            28.6404,
                                            17.9532
                                          ],
                                          [
                                            "Category 2",
                                            57.5819,
                                            27.1754
                                          ],
                                          [
                                            "Category 3",
                                            4.4474,
                                            2.4474
                                          ]
                                        ]
                            for each_header in chart_header:
                                e_worksheet.Range(str(chr(65)) + str(count)).Value = each_header
                                count = count + 1
                            temp_count = 1
                            for each_row in range(0, len(chart_data)):
                                for each_col in range(0, len(chart_data[each_row])):
                                    e_worksheet.Range(str(chr(65 + temp_count)) + str(each_col + 1)).Value = \
                                    chart_data[each_row][each_col]
                                temp_count = temp_count + 1

                            Slide.Shapes(1).Chart.SetSourceData(Source=e_worksheet.Range("$A$1:$D$3"))
                            e_workbook.Close(SaveChanges=1)

                            print("Chart data updated. Please check the output file")
                            chart.Refresh()
                        except Exception as e:
                            print("ERROR <Inner Try Block>: " + str(e))
                            traceback.print_exc()

    presentation.SaveAs(output)
    application.Quit()
except Exception as e:
    print("ERROR : " + str(e))
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Getting following error when I am calling the chart.SetSourceData method
pywintypes.com_error: `(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147467259), None)`